# disconnect gmail when cheked in from another mobile

Tags: gmail

I checked in to my g-mail using a friends mobile.
Now that I exited from my g-mail the friends phone seems connected to my Google account. How do I disconnect my account from that phone? now I can't check in from my own android phone , please help urgently.. thx

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways:-

1. If you have access to the phone (or trust your friend to do it), just delete your Google account from your friend's phone. In the main **Settings** app, under **Accounts**, find **Google** in the list and click on it. Then click your account and click **Remove account**.
2. If you've switched your Google account to use app-specific passwords, then you can simply revoke the Gmail password you used to sign in on your friend's phone. Nothing else will be affected.
3. If you can't wait for your friend, and you're not using app-specific passwords, then just log into your Google account from a web browser and change your password. It will sign out on all the devices and you'll get a prompt asking you to enter the new password.

That said, there's something that doesn't quite add up. It's possible to be signed in and use Gmail from more than one Android device at a time. Signing in on your friend's phone shouldn't make your phone stop working, so it could be a coincidence, which means that signing out on your friend's phone won't fix anything.